# I keep getting "env: node: No such file or directory" running Grunt on Eclipse as an external tool under MacOS Yosemite

Tags: eclipse, node.js, macos, gruntjs, osx-yosemite

Eclipse (Luna) is clearly launching grunt as the external build tool. However, the Eclipse console keeps showing the "env: node: No such file or directory" message and the grunt tasks do not get to run.

I can successfully run grunt on the command line (outside Eclipse) after moving to the project directory.

The node installer did place it on /usr/local/bin/node but apparently grunt is expecting it somewhere else.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 21):

if you are using Homebrew try

```
brew unlink node
```

then

```
 brew link node
```

Comment: I had to change permissions on the directory first

Answer (score 9):

I discovered that grunt is apparently expecting node to live on `/usr/bin`, yet the installer placed it on `/usr/local/bin`.

Solution:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

Hope helps.

Comment: i get **ln: /usr/bin/node: Operation not permitted** then

Comment: ln: /usr/bin/node: Operation not permitted  on mac m/c how to resolve it ?here link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495229/env-node-no-such-file-or-directory-using-jenkings-windows-machine-node-and

Answer (score 3):

The "External Tools Configurations" dialog has a tab for setting the environment the command will run in. In this tab, press "Select..." and select "PATH...". Once it's there you can edit the Value to append ":/usr/local/bin". After this both "node" and "npm" are found and commands work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
brew unlink node
brew link node
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, please add a short explanation to your post and describe what your commands actually do and how they solve the initial problem. Don't just drop some lines of code.