# env: node: No such file or directory (using Jenkins, Windows machine, node and a remote web interface)

Tags: node.js, cordova, jenkins, npm, jenkins-agent

Lately I am doing an iOS build where I remotely launch a MacOS agent, using a remote web interface through my IP address.

I already tried uninstalling node / npm and reinstalling it, but it still gets the same error after I install [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/).

I also checked if my directory for node wasn't wrong and it's fine:

[image]

I also already tried the solution of putting `set +e` at the top of my shell script, but after that it still doesn't work.

I am already trying to figure this problem out for 5 days and it still isn't solved, so I hope you guys can try to help me out further in this situation.

This error takes place when the `iOS` build starts.

```
Started by upstream project "CordovaHelloWorld" build number 97
originally caused by:
Started by user (user)
Building remotely on mac-slave (ios) in workspace 
/Users/(username)/Desktop/jenkinsMacSlave/workspace/CordovaHelloWorld/PLATFORM/ios
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 
# timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/(user)/Jenkins 
# timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/(user)/Jenkins
> git --version 
# timeout=10
> git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/(user)/Jenkins 
+refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/
Checking out Revision b08e07983673bdc08dcb6e81d65e83a3cb5edc5c 
(origin/Jenkinsios)
> git config core.sparsecheckout 
# timeout=10
> git checkout -f b08e07983673bdc08dcb6e81d65e83a3cb5edc5c
> git rev-list b08e07983673bdc08dcb6e81d65e83a3cb5edc5c 
# timeout=10
[ios] $ /bin/sh -xe 
/var/folders/sj/01rfz4rx1ws_smjvggb_klzw0000gq/T/jenkins150886583207745932.sh
+ set +e
+ /usr/local/bin/cordova platform rm ios --no-telemetry --no-update-notifier
env: node: No such file or directory
+ /usr/local/bin/cordova platform add ios --no-telemetry --no-update-notifier
env: node: No such file or directory
+ /usr/local/bin/cordova build ios --no-telemetry --no-update-notifier
env: node: No such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have tried many and many solutions, but none worked.
I really hope this problem gets fixed soon, already thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I tried these following answers already:

1. https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3911
2. [Express.js: No Such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914715/express-js-no-such-file-or-directory)
3. [Cannot install NodeJs: /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320901/cannot-install-nodejs-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory)
4. [browserify error /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886217/browserify-error-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution has been found. It was a path problem with mac slave. needed to add environment variable in Jenkins: `PATH + LOCAL_BIN` ---- `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. The variable created was named: PATH + LOCAL_BIN or it was 2 variables PATH and LOCAL_BIN? Was it done automatically on your side or you had to call that new variable somehow? Thanks a lot